# Add dynamically new row (view) on button press

Tags: react-native

I would like a new view to be created upon button press to show a new row, and also add a new empty object in the "fields" array (upon same key press).

```
this.state = {
    countrows:1,
    fields: [
        {
            month: '',
            id: 0,
            unitrate: '',
            budget: '',
        }
    }
}

onAddClickHandler = () => {
    var newObject=({month: '',id: '',unitrate: '', budget: ''}); 
    let newF = this.state.fields.push(newObject);
    this.setState({ fields: newF })
}


<View style={styles.List}>
    {
        this.state.fields.map((a, i) => {
            return <Content key={i}/>
        })
    }
</View>

<Button  onPress={this.onAddClickHandler} />
```

Comment: Try with `let { fields } = this.state;
fields.push(newObject);
this.setState({ fields });` in your onAddClickHandler method

Comment: problem not solved

Comment: Mostly code formatting

Comment: Mostly code formatting

Comment: So, what's the actual problem? What happens?

Comment: solved by just using this syntax-> 

onAddClickHandler=()=>{
        
        this.setState({fields: [...this.state.fields, " "]  })

Answer (score 0):

the whole bunch of my hurdle is only this line

```
    this.setState({fields: [...this.state.fields, " "]  })
```

it adds the new empty object in the array and also adds new row to the view container.